# find next line sometimes overwrites existing data

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I hope you can help I have the below code as part of a larger macro but instead of pasting the values into the next available row at the bottom it is sometimes overwriting existing data.

```
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
    Dim copySheet As Worksheet
    Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
    Set copySheet = Worksheets("Helper")
    Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Purchases 2021")
    copySheet.Range("A2:K2").Copy
    pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

The worksheet is used to generate purchase orders and record purchases made, when the button is clicked the macro generates an email of the purchase order pastes the details onto the next row of columns A-K in the tracking sheet where there are some formulae and other manually input data in columns L-AK which are used by the finance team to track goods received and invoicing.
It seems to only be happening where a user is inputting multiple purchase orders in one sitting but I can't replicate the error so am having trouble working out where it is falling over.
The sheet is locked so it cannot be accidental it must be something in the macro.

edited to add whole code (I have deleted the password here):

```
'Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Sheets("Purchase order form").Unprotect Password:=
Sheets("Helper").Unprotect Password:=
Sheets("Helper2").Unprotect Password:=
Sheets("recurring orders 2021").Unprotect Password:=
Sheets("Purchases 2021").Unprotect Password:=
Range("M7").Copy
Range("M7").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

Calculate

Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set rng = Nothing
Set rng = Sheet1.Range("A1:N43").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
If rng Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "The selection is not a range or the sheet is protected. " & _
       vbNewLine & "Please correct and try again.", vbOKOnly
Exit Sub
End If

With Application
.EnableEvents = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
.To = Sheet1.Range("H12")
.CC = "xxx@xxx.xxx"
.BCC = ""
.Subject = Sheet1.Range("M12")
.HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
.Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0
With Application
.EnableEvents = True
.ScreenUpdating = True
End With

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet
Set copySheet = Worksheets("Helper")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Purchases 2021")
copySheet.Range("A2:L2").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Sheets("Purchase order form").Protect Password:=
Sheets("Helper").Protect Password:=
Sheets("Helper2").Protect Password:=
Sheets("recurring orders 2021").Protect Password:=, AllowFiltering:=True
Sheets("Purchases 2021").Protect Password:=, AllowFiltering:=True
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Dim TempFile As String
Dim TempWB As Workbook

TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"
rng.Copy
Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
With TempWB.Sheets(1)
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
    .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
    .Cells(1).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    On Error Resume Next
    .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
    .DrawingObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
End With
With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
     SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
     Filename:=TempFile, _
     Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
     Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
     HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
    .Publish (True)
End With
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
ts.Close
RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                      "align=left x:publishsource=")

TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

Kill TempFile
Set ts = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

EDIT***I have been made aware that the workbook is sometimes being save with the paste sheet filtered - could that be causing the issue?***

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the complete code. Also run the macro with F8 key and report back

Comment: The Dim refers to copySheet and pasteSheet but the code refers to copySheetA  and pasteSheetA ? You have Application.ScreenUpdating = False twice ? You need to ensure cell "A2" is not blank.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, I can add the whole thing but it is huge and it is only this part that doesn't work, the rest works fine.

Comment: Hi CDP1802, sorry the errors you found were transcription errors, that will teach me to not proof read the code! Cell A2 cannot be blank as it is populated by a formula that will always enter a value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help @cdp1802, I have found the problem, there was a hidden cell that was blank for some entries, and where these cells are blank then the macro is assuming the row is blank and putting the new data in that row.
Thanks again for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't locate the root cause you could program defensively to warn the user and avoid overwriting existing data.

```vb
    Dim copySheet As Worksheet, pasteSheet As Worksheet
    Dim iRow As Long, rng As Range
    
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set copySheet = .Sheets("Helper")
        Set pasteSheet = .Sheets("Purchases 2021")
    End With
        
    With pasteSheet
        iRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Set rng = .Range("A" & iRow).Resize(1, 12) ' A-L

        ' ensure range is empty
        While WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0
            MsgBox rng.Address & " not blank, trying next one", vbExclamation
            Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)
        Wend
       
        rng = copySheet.Range("A2:L2").Value
        MsgBox "inserted into row " & rng.Row, vbInformation
    End With
```

Comment: thanks @CDP1802 I was hoping to avoid using message boxes as people just ignore them! I guess I could use the end macro functionality, but really would rather try to find the root cause and eliminate it.